# Material-UI Package not working: React / Rails / Browserify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, browserify, material-ui

I have downloaded 'material-ui' package and added to my package.json file through NPM. It is displaying in my `package.json` file. However, I'm not able to access components like `AppBar` as my browser is telling me it's not defined. I've attempted adding a global variable in my application.js file, but this isn actually crashing the app:

`var MaterialUI = require('material-ui');`

I'm using Rails 4 and Ruby 2.1 with Browserify. Definitely frustrating, I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thank you for any help/pointers in the right direction you can give me!

Comment: I assume you're using Browserify to render your JS side (instead of, say, react-rails).   If so, you should just be able to do `<MaterialUI.AppBar title='...'>` in your `render()` method to get going.   There's also an example app (albeit very brief) in the Material-UI package for browserify (note that it doesn't assume Rails is involved).

Comment: I ended up re-installing React w/o Sprockets. This helped tremendously. I would post this as an answer but am unsure if this is the right way to do it. Basically, I'm now posting 'requires' to React and all needed components when needed, at the top of each included component. It's more modular and 'node'-like this way. Sprockets definitely has its limitations when working outside a strictly Rails framework. Thanks for your help @rdnewman

Comment: If you want the full npm experience but while taking advantage of rails' asset pipeline, you can consider the gem react_webpack_rails (https://github.com/netguru/react_webpack_rails) (though it uses webpack not browserify) or react_on_rails gem (https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails).  Both replace `react-rails` gem but extend that functionality.  This is how I use React, Material-UI and Rails together.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll definitely keep this in mind. : )

Comment: I'm doing similar exercise myself. I've made a repo for my react-rails practice (using material ui), might be helpful for you too:
https://github.com/sidazhou/react_rails_skeleton